# How to read this talisman (符)?

Tags: writing

I came across this talisman (符) the other day:

> [image]

I can recognize some characters in there, but mostly I'm just stumped by the entire thing. How are talisman supposed to be read? How can I read this one?

Answer (score 1):

I think I see this:

```
會 會
敕 敕
地 押
神 百
助 煞
財 氣
通 罡
捷
令
罡
```

I am not certain on my choice of "會", it could be "金母", if it is a name of a deity or something.

In that case, it would be this:

```
金 金
母 母
敕 敕
地 押
神 百
助 煞
財 氣
通 罡
捷
令
罡
```

Comment: IMO the top characters look like 金. I think 金 makes sense (this looks like a fortune-beckoning talisman, 助財神).

Comment: @dROOOze I initially had 金母 instead of 會, but 金母 is not a word or phrase that can make any sense. But thanks. It might make sense if it's a name I think.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the talisman consist of ancient chinese characters tracked way backed to the ancient dynasty, as such, no one read the talisman characters, as the talisman is mostly used for prayers or used to give good luck or good fortune which is usually hung up or paste on the doors of each family household.

Answer (score 0):

Let me confirm @Daniel Cheung's answer. After a bit of search, it's definitely 金母 at the beginning. It designates specifically [瑤池金母](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%A5%BF%E7%8E%8B%E6%AF%8D) as known as 西王母. You can find a bunch of similar talismans online with adequate keywords.